# Starting a Ruby project: github + build tool

Tags: ruby, github, directory-structure

I am starting out to play around with Ruby and trying to make a desktop app using Ruby and wxRuby.

So, to start out with a new ruby only project, I have few questions:

1. I need a standard directory structure, what is the best possible way to do it? I tried out [newgem](http://drnic.github.com/newgem/) with details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362/directory-layout-for-pure-ruby-project), but it seems that that the newgem website is not updated and the folder structure described on their website is different that what is generated on my machine. More over, it requires a rubyforge repo, but I want my project on github, so how do I get around it?
   (I think newgem used hoe to create the folder structure)
2. I need a use a build tool, I have used ant and maven for Java, so what is the best build tool for Ruby only projects?
3. What is the "standard" way you guys make a Ruby project?

I just need a headstart, like in Java, I use Eclipse, create a new project, create an ant file and I am good to go. Now, since I am not using an IDE for Ruby (using textmate), how should I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler)
2. [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/)

And here an example: [Create your first ruby gem and release it to gemcutter](http://sirupsen.com/create-your-first-ruby-gem-and-release-it-to-gemcutter/)

As for github, they stopped direct gem building but still you can host your source there easily.

To distribute your application as executable have a look at [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/) or [OCRA](http://github.com/larsch/ocra/)

Comment: So, I will create a gem and upload it to gecutter. If  I want to make an executable, how can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by executable? Something like an .exe file?

Comment: yea, say i want to share my app via a downloadable link on my web site. The end user just needs to use my app and he does not have gems installed. So, I basically need to bundle my app as .exe (pc), .app (mac) and Linux executable

Comment: newgem has a feature of creating executables, does jeweler has a similar kind of feature? (similar to an executable jar in java)